# Script to delete everything on line after third word

Tags: python, bash

I need to delete everything in the file after the third file. I have no idea how to write this script though, can be either bash or python.

The file looks like this:

```
ssessment   assay   5.83    8   10  5   6   4   5   7   3
incubate    breed   6.40    10  6   10  5   7   4   7   7
incubate    develop 7.20    7   7   8   6   7   7   9   10
```

The file after the script should look

```
ssessment   assay   5.83
incubate    breed   6.40
incubate    develop 7.20
```

Comment: There are many ways of doing this simple task, what have you tried so far that led you to failure ?

Comment: I tried using sed utility but I didnt get very far though. cant find any solution on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
with open(filename, "r") as infile:                             #Read file
    data = [line.split()[:3] for line in infile.readlines()]    #Using list slicing to get only the required 3 elements 

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:                            #Write File
    for i in data:
        outfile.write("{0}\n".format(" ".join(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial `awk` task: print the first three fields. Assuming tab (`\t`) is the field separator:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $3}' file.txt
```

- `-F '\t'` sets the input field separator as tab
- `-v OFS='\t'` sets the output field separator as tab
- `{print $1, $2, $3}` prints the first three fields separated by `OFS` (which we have defined to be tab)

---

On the other hand, if the fields are space/whitespace separated and you want them to be space separated in the output this gets very easy as `awk` takes whitespace(s) as input field separators by default:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `awk` in bash, but in python it's also straightforward. Read in the lines, split them on the whitespace (which is the default) and write out the result. If you need to keep the whitespace, then this code will do it:

```
lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
output = open(output_file_name, 'w')
for line in lines:
    contents = ''.join(line.split(' '))
    item_ctr=0
    for item in contents:
        if item != '':
            item_ctr += 1
            output.write(item+' ')
            if item_ctr == 3:
                break
        else:
            output.write(' ')
    output.write('\n')
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

when I saw this question, I came up with this first:

```
awk 'NF=3' file
```

If you want the output content to be separated by `TAB`:

```
awk 'NF=3' OFS="\t" file
```

Comment: You can clearly see this is a duplicate, why are you still posting an answer identical to one in the linked duplicate?

Comment: @123 It is not marked as duplicated when I posted it...